# Sort data by an increase of 4

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sort code that sorts my data by several criteria. However, the numbers should increase by four each time, rather than just in increasing order. As an example, I might have the number 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, and 9 but I would want them listed as 0, 4, 8 then 1, 5, 9.

```
Dim num As Range
Dim sortcode As Range
Dim sortnum As Range
Dim firstsort As Range
rangevalue = ("I2:I" & rlastrow)
Set firstsort = Range(rangevalue)

rangevalue = ("L2:L" & rlastrow)
Set sortcode = Range(rangevalue)

rangevalue = ("J2:J" & rlastrow)
Set sortnum = Range(rangevalue)

wr.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wr.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=firstsort _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wr.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sortcode _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wr.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sortnum _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wr.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:L" & rlastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Is it possible to modify my code in the sortnum field that will require an increase of four rather than just increasing order?

Comment: Can you add a helper column where you calculate `=MOD(originalnumber, 4)`, and then sort on the modulo 4 answer with a higher priority than the original number.

Comment: Might be best to either use YowE3K's suggestion or create a new spreadsheet that has each row organized into this by using a function that will find and detect each nth number

Answer (score 2):

@YowE3K comment about helper column is sound advice.

Another option: Use a custom sort order.

If your list is small and manageable, you could manually write it like this:

```
wr.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=firstsort _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    CustomOrder:= "0,4,8,12,16,1,5,9,13,17,2,6,10,14,18,3,7,11,13,19", _ 
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

This only sorts 0 to 19

Example:

[image]

---

If your list is larger you can programmatically generate your custom order string to how ever large you need and set it to a variable.

```
CustomOrder:=mySortString
```